# Specifying custom cursor in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to specify a custom cursor when a user moves their mouse over a . I can specify the system default cursors and this works fine, but I can't get custom cursors to work;

```
import CustomCursor from '../custompointer.svg';
...
<div style={{ cursor: 'url(' + CustomCursor + ', auto)' }}>
```

I've seen some solutions online, but these are lengthy for what I suspect is a simple solution.

Comment: How big is your cursor image SVG file? There's limits on the resolution

Comment: You can do that using css: https://medium.com/@benzbraunstein/how-to-make-custom-css-cursors-using-react-fd1a5cca9400

Answer (score 0):

change your code from :

```
cursor: 'url(' + CustomCursor + ', auto)'
```

to

```
cursor: "url(" + CustomCursor + "), auto"
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-snow-im111)