# Custom cursor in react not working despite following other question's instruction

Tags: reactjs, cursor

I'm trying to rewrite my portfolio in React.  One feature my old porfolio has was there was a custom cursor for every project tile (your mouse hovered over the tile, the cursor would change).  This was a simple enough operation in the original, but I can't get it to work in React.  As far as I can tell, I copied the instruction in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66840945/9883126) to a tee, but it still doesn't work.

Here's my code, I know this is a lot but I figured I should give you some broad context:

```
    import React from "react";
import crystal from "./images/crystal2.png";
import PortProject from "./PortProject.js";
import DownProject from "./DownProject.js";
import PortProjectWIP from "./PortProjectWIP.js";
import Brightstar from "./cursors/brightstar.cur"

function Portfolio(){
    return(
        <div>
        <div class = "row">
<div class = "col-sm-1">
</div>

<h1 style={{padding: "5px", display: "inline", borderRadius:"25px"}}>Solo Endeavors</h1>
<hr />
<br />
<br />
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class = "col-sm-2"></div>
 
  <PortProject caption = "Crystal Game" style = {{cursor: "url(" + Brightstar + "), auto"}} link = "https://dennismarkham.github.io/week-4-game/" 
  langs = "HTML, CSS, Javascript, JQuery, local storage, SASS" alt = "Crystal Game" 
  image = "https://dennismarkham.github.io/ConceptPortfolio/images/crystal.png" />
```

And there is the PortProject code:

```
    import React from "react";

function PortProject(props){
    return(
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="thumbnail" data-toggle="tool-tip" title={props.langs}>
      <a href={props.link}>
        <img style = {{height: "250px"}} src={props.image} alt={props.alt}
        />
        <div class="caption">
          <p>{props.caption}</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

        )
}
export default PortProject;
```

Comment: Can you add the PortProject component to your question too

Comment: Yeah, just a minute.

Comment: You don't pass `props.style` to any of the rendered components in PortProject, it's just ignored

Comment: Okay, I think I get what you're saying.  First I tried to do this in the style sheet: [caption = "Crystal Game"]
{
cursor: url('./cursors/brightstar.cur'), auto !important;
}  But it didn't work